# Draggable, resizable divs with z-index

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

What I'm trying to create is 3 divs inside a container. Allow the divs to be draggable and resizable without one div affecting the other ones if doing so.

So far so good. But now I want the latest clicked / dragged div to always be on top. So with a bit of jQuery it was quite easy to accomplish this. But always keeping them in order seems to be a lot harder. For example:

Order: DIV1 / DIV2 / DIV3 -> Clicked DIV2
Order: DIV2 / DIV1 / DIV3 -> Clicked DIV3
Order: DIV3 / DIV2 / DIV1 -> Clicked DIV2
Order: DIV2 / DIV3 / DIV1 etc etc

It's kind of hard to explain what exactly I mean. But a live example of this code can be found here: http://www.icecub.nl/mychat. I've tried making a fiddle as well, but I couldn't shrink the divs far enough to make it viable for a fiddle.

Anyway, the code part that's important is:

```
var curIndex;

$("#boxlist, #mainchat, #userlist").mousedown(function(){
    curIndex = $(this).css("z-index");
    $(this).css("z-index", 15);
}).bind("mouseup", function(){
    var curElement = $(this).attr("id");
    switch(curElement){
        case "boxlist":
            var userList = $("#userlist").css("z-index");
            var mainChat = $("#mainchat").css("z-index");
            if(userList > mainChat){
                $("#userlist").css("z-index", 5);
                $("#mainchat").css("z-index", 1);
            } else {
                $("#userlist").css("z-index", 1);
                $("#mainchat").css("z-index", 5);
            }
            break;
        case "mainchat":
            var boxList = $("#boxlist").css("z-index");
            var userList = $("#userlist").css("z-index");
            if(boxList > userList){
                $("#boxlist").css("z-index", 5);
                $("#userlist").css("z-index", 1);
            } else {
                $("#boxlist").css("z-index", 1);
                $("#userlist").css("z-index", 5);
            }
            break;
        case "userlist":
            var boxList = $("#boxlist").css("z-index");
            var mainChat = $("mainchat").css("z-index");
            if(boxList > mainChat){
                $("#boxlist").css("z-index", 5);
                $("#mainchat").css("z-index", 1);
            } else {
                $("#boxlist").css("z-index", 1);
                $("#mainchat").css("z-index", 5);
            }
            break;
        default:
            $("#boxlist").css("z-index", 1);
            $("#mainchat").css("z-index", 10);
            $("#userlist").css("z-index", 5);
    }
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#userlist, #mainchat, #boxlist")
  .draggable({ containment: "section" })
  .resizable();

 $("#colorChanger").on("change", function(){
  $("head link#theme").attr("href", "layout/css/"+$(this).val()+".css");
 });

 $("#boxlist, #mainchat, #userlist").mousedown(function(){
  $(this).css("z-index", 15);
 }).bind("mouseup", function(){
  var curElement = $(this).attr("id");
  switch(curElement){
   case "boxlist":
    var userList = $("#userlist").css("z-index");
    var mainChat = $("#mainchat").css("z-index");
    if(userList > mainChat){
     $("#userlist").css("z-index", 5);
     $("#mainchat").css("z-index", 1);
    } else {
     $("#userlist").css("z-index", 1);
     $("#mainchat").css("z-index", 5);
    }
    break;
   case "mainchat":
    var boxList = $("#boxlist").css("z-index");
    var userList = $("#userlist").css("z-index");
    if(boxList > userList){
     $("#boxlist").css("z-index", 5);
     $("#userlist").css("z-index", 1);
    } else {
     $("#boxlist").css("z-index", 1);
     $("#userlist").css("z-index", 5);
    }
    break;
   case "userlist":
    var boxList = $("#boxlist").css("z-index");
    var mainChat = $("mainchat").css("z-index");
    if(boxList > mainChat){
     $("#boxlist").css("z-index", 5);
     $("#mainchat").css("z-index", 1);
    } else {
     $("#boxlist").css("z-index", 1);
     $("#mainchat").css("z-index", 5);
    }
    break;
   default:
    $("#boxlist").css("z-index", 1);
    $("#mainchat").css("z-index", 10);
    $("#userlist").css("z-index", 5);
  }
 });
});
```

```css
* {
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: 13px;
}

html {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

section {
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
 height: 100vh;
}

#chat_table {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;
 height: calc(100% - 73px);
}

.list_table {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;
}

.title, .title_mid, .title_right {
 height: 20px;
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#main_title {
 height: 20px;
}

#main_chat {
 height: 100%;
}

#main_text {
 height: 50px;
}

#userlist {
 width: 250px;
 height: 500px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 left: 770px;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 5;
}

#mainchat {
 margin-left: 5px;
 left: 270px;
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 10;
}

#boxlist {
 float: left;
 width: 250px;
 height: 500px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
}

#chatLines {
 width: calc(100% - 6px);
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 border: solid 1px #000000;
 resize: none;
}

#chatInput {
 width: calc(100% - 192px);
 height: 50px;
 margin: 0px;
 border: solid 1px #000000;
 resize: none;
 margin-left: 1px;
 margin-top: 1px;
}

#usernameInput {
 width: calc(100% - 6px);
 height: 24px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 border: solid 1px #000000;
}
#connectButton {
 width: 100%;
 height: 28px;
 margin-left: -1px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#usersList {
 border: solid 1px #000000;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 width: calc(100% - 6px);
 height: calc(100% - 110px);
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 display: block;
 overflow: auto;
}
#sendButton {
 width: 184px;
 height: 54px;
 float: right;
 margin-right:2px;
}
.title {
 width: 197px;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 background: #ffffff url("http://www.icecub.nl/images/blue/title.png") no-repeat left top;
}

.title_mid {
 background: #ffffff url("http://www.icecub.nl/images/blue/title_mid.png") repeat-x left top;
}

.title_right {
 width: 9px;
 background: #ffffff url("http://www.icecub.nl/images/blue/title_corner_right.png") no-repeat left top;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<section>
 <div id="boxlist">
  <table class="list_table">
   <tbody>
    <tr id="main_title">
     <td class="title">Opties</td>
     <td class="title_mid"></td>
     <td class="title_right"></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <select id="colorChanger">
   <option value="blue">Blauw</option>
   <option value="green">Groen</option>
   <option value="red">Rood</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <div id="mainchat">
  <table id="chat_table">
   <tbody>
    <tr id="main_title">
     <td class="title">Chat</td>
     <td class="title_mid"></td>
     <td class="title_right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="main_chat">
     <td colspan="3">
      <textarea id='chatLines' readonly='readonly'></textarea>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <textarea id='chatInput' placeholder='bericht'></textarea>
  <input id='sendButton' type='button' value='Verstuur' onclick='cb.onClickSend()' />
 </div>
 <div id="userlist">
  <table class="list_table">
   <tbody>
    <tr id="main_title">
     <td class="title">Leden</td>
     <td class="title_mid"></td>
     <td class="title_right"></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <input id='usernameInput' type='text' placeholder='Gebruikersnaam' /><br />
  <input id='connectButton' type='button' value='Verbinden' onclick='cb.onClickConnect()' /><br />
  <ul id='usersList'><li style='text-align:center;'>(niet verbonden)</li></ul>
 </div>
</section>
```

As you can see I've tried fixing it myself with a bunch of if statements. I know it's an ugly way to do it, but I couldn't think of something better for the moment. Unfortunetely it doesn't work though. When placing both "boxlist" and "userlist" over "mainchat", and "userlist" is clicked, it pushes "boxlist" behind "mainchat" while it shouldn't. I think this has to do with the variables not being integers but strings instead and therefor can't be compared the way I'm trying to do. Not sure though.

Comment: try using the inbuilt editor to create a demo. it has full screen view

Comment: @TJ Let me check. Never used that one before but I'll do my best

Comment: @TJ Added the code snippet. But for some reason it seems to ignore the jquery-ui library. Therefor dragging isn't working? - Edit: Never mind, fixed it.

Comment: Even with higher `z-index`, your first box always stays behind the second https://jsfiddle.net/bpy9zq76/

Comment: @TJ Ye I had the same problem. Maciej below however made a very easy solution. Can't believe I didn't think of that myself, haha

Comment: Well his solution doesn't seem to work either https://jsfiddle.net/bpy9zq76/1/

Comment: @TJ Seems to work perfectly fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/o7j09jxL/

Comment: hmm.. the left one disappears the moment I click and drag it ( chrome on ubuntu)

Comment: @TJ Ye the design is a little bit off in Chrome on Windows as well. Though it doesn't disappear. Perhaps it has something to do with the divs only being draggable inside the section container? `containment: "section"` will try to force each div inside section when the screen isn't big enough to display all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that: instead of keeping an eye on elements ordering you could just do it kind of loosely coupled way, that is, every time user clicks a div you'd increment it's index by one, this way ordering should remain as you wanted:

```
var curIndex = 2;

$("#boxlist, #mainchat, #userlist").mousedown(function(){
    $(this).css(zIndex, ++curIndex);
});
```

Comment: Sir, you saved my day! I had to fix the css a bit as well to make this work (put all on z-index 1 on load), but after that it works like a charm! Thanks a lot!